# Why javac sometimes creates unnecessary copies of variables?

Tags: java, javac, bytecode

I have code looks like this:

```
boolean[] array = new boolean[200];
int[] indexes = {10, 42, 62, 74};
while(true) {
    //some code here
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j : indexes) {
        sb.append(array[j] ? '1' : '0');
    }
}
```

Bytecode for this:

```
ASTORE 3 //"indexes" array
...
ALOAD 3
ASTORE 8
ALOAD 8
ARRAYLENGTH
...
```

I am not sure about why javac copy ref to array into another local var.

Comment: What part of this bytecode *"copy ref to array into another local var"* ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard `ALOAD 3` followed by `ASTORE 8`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The for-each loop is converted into something like this:

```
{
    int[] hidden_array_ref = indexes;
    int hidden_length = hidden_array_ref.length;
    for(int hidden_counter = 0; hidden_counter < hidden_length; hidden_counter++) {
        int j = hidden_array_ref[hidden_counter];
        sb.append(array[j] ? '1' : '0');
    }
}
```

In particular, notice `int[] hidden_array_ref = indexes;`. That's the copy you are asking about.

The compiler does it this way so that if you write something like:

```
for(int j : indexes) {
    indexes = new int[0];
    sb.append(array[j] ? '1' : '0');
}
```

the assignment to `indexes` doesn't affect the loop.

Comment: Not sure how does that answer *"why javac copy ref to array into another local var"*

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard it's the ref to `indexes` that is being copied (into another hidden local variable, which I've called `hidden_array_ref`)

Comment: Oh, that's what I missed.

Comment: Wow, ty. I was thought that changing array inside loop it's programmer problem or not allowed at all.
I try it now with normal for loop like this:

    `int[] array = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {}`

And no copies was generated. So we allowed to do some unpredictable manipulations with array in this loop?

Comment: @saroff: the definition is simply that if you use `for(var : expression)`, the `expression` is evaluated only once. It may be another local variable like in you case, but think of `for(byte b: Files.readAllBytes(pathToMyFile))`; in this case the file is read only once at the beginning of the loop, not in every iteration…